# Difference between a wave and a signal?

Tags: waves, terminology

A wave is a movement in time in a medium. It needs a medium . The energy is transferred due to this movement in the medium. In such a case , it is called a wave. For eg: Electromagnetic waves, light waves.

Whereas a signal signifies something. It carries information in the wave. Eg: In Band signalling, out band signalling, dialling signal etc.-it signals the receiving device to do something with what it receives.

So what is the difference between a wave and a signal?

Comment: I can't understand exact meaning....

Comment: Your first statement is not true. Not every wave (as you mentioned an electromagnetic wave) need a medium. But I'dont really understand what you're asking? Could you pleas clearify your question.

Comment: "Signal" in this context usually just means some time-dependent function which is being analyzed.  It's almost too broad to give a precise description, and does not have any specific physical meaning.

Comment: then what is the meaning of a wave means  it carries information but in the case of signal sometimes it carry and sometimes it doesn't carry it takes into account only when it is a function of time

Comment: Broadly speaking, a wave is a traveling disturbance in some kind of field.  You're trying to over-define these words, and it's causing you problems.  Natural language always requires context and interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

A wave is a solution of a differential wave equation, basically sinusoidal solutions.

A signal is a meta level to waves when waves are used to transfer signals.

example: The alphabet is a level. Words written using the alphabet are a meta level based on the alphabet

The sinusoidal solutions for waves are used to describe signals by the concept of [wavepackets, which are also solutions](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html) of the same equation for specific boundary conditions.

[image: wvpckt]

Comment: @CosmasZachos ok, will do